# Raise an error and after that return a value in Python

Tags: python

I want to raise an error and then return a value.

```
raise ValueError('Max Iter Reached')
return x
```

And make both lines work.

Now I found this question is stupid and I decided to print an error message.

```
print 'Max Iter Reached'
return x
```

Comment: Why would you want to raise an error and return? That makes no sense

Comment: Nothing will be executed after a `raise`. If you absolutely want to raise something then you need to handle that raise in a `try/except` and then return

Answer (score 6):

This is impossible.  A function can *either* return a value *or* raise an exception.  It *cannot* do both.  Calling `return` or `raise` will absolutely terminate the function.

You could encode a return value inside the exception message, like this:

```
raise SomeException('my value is 5')
```

Or you could return a tuple of an exception *and* a value:

```
return (SomeException('hello'), 5)
```

Comment: why is impossible ? check my answer.

Comment: @levi your answer returns `value` and does _not_ raise an exception.  (Okay, it raises an exception _locally_.  But the caller will never see it, which I assume is what he wants.)

Comment: I got u, but I think OP wants to raise an exception then, get it and return the value. Not raise and return at same time.

Comment: @levi I assumed he was asking for both.  If he really meant "raise an exception locally, handle it, and then return a value", then good on you :-)

Comment: @JohnGordon Originally I mean raise an exception and, after that, return a value. Thank you for your answer and I updated my question.

Answer (score 3):

It does not make sense but In case you need it.

```
def your_method(self):
    ......
    try:
        raise ValueError('Max Iter Reached')
    except ValueError as e:
        return value
```

Comment: That will only work in Python 2. Python 3, the `except` will have to be `except ValueError as e:`

Comment: Now I decide to print an error message instead of raise a ValueError.

Comment: @Arthur well, in `e` you got the exception. You can get the message from it.

Comment: @levi Did you mean `return e`?